# javascript autocomplete es6 imported classes

Tags: javascript

I am a little bit confused because I thought this used to work, but now I can't seem to get it working in either vim or atom.

If I define a class in one file

```
export class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("foo")
  }
}
```

and then import it in another file

```
import { Foo } from './foo'

var f = new Foo();
f.
```

I want to have an autocomplete that will complete the typing of `Foo` when I am calling `new()` and also complete the method `foo()` when `.` is typed.

Standard in many languages, and I am sure there must be a tool for this (I thought it was `tern` but it is not working for me at the moment)

Comment: Are you sure this is a JS question? Seems more suited for your IDE.

Comment: yes I am asking about IDE agnostic tools, as I have said I have extensively tried to get various things to work in vim and atom and I realized I cannot even answer the simple question of if there is a tool that will complete my example above.